# How to lock slider and prevent updating of values with mouse into dat.GUI menu

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I try to implement a way to prevent the updating of values with mouse (actually when the `three.js` animation has started, launched with a click on button).

For the moment, I have the following `dat.GUI` menu:

[image]

Once "start" button is clicked, I would like to prevent user from modifying with mouse the parameters "`Rotation x`" and "`Rotation y`".

Here is the concerned part of code for this menu:

```
// Create GUI
var gui = new dat.GUI({
      autoplace: false, 
      width: 350,
          height: 9 * 32 - 1
});

var params = {
      GreatCircle : '',
      Rotationx : torusRotationInitX,
      Rotationy : torusRotationInitY,
      StartingVector : '',
      ComponentVectorTheta : 15.0,
      ComponentVectorPhi : 15.0,
      CovariantDerivativeVector : '',
      ComponentCovariantDerivativeTheta : 15.0,
      ComponentCovariantDerivativePhi : 15.0
};

// Set parameters for GUI
gui.add(params, 'GreatCircle').name('Great Circle ');
controllerRotationx = gui.add(params, 'Rotationx', 0, 2*Math.PI, 0.001).name('Rotation x ');
controllerRotationy = gui.add(params, 'Rotationy', 0, 2*Math.PI, 0.001).name('Rotation y ');
...
```

When I click on reset button, I call the following function:

```
  // Reset Button
  resetButton.onclick = function ResetParameters() {

  ...

  // Reinitialize parameters into gui
  params.Rotationx = torusRotationInitX; 
  params.Rotationy = torusRotationInitY; 

  for (var i in gui.__controllers) {
     gui.__controllers[i].updateDisplay();
  }

render();

}
```

I don't know if there is an option for controller to lock these sliders which usually change their values. Is it possible?

### Update 1

Maybe I could wrapper the dat.GUI menu into a div and make this div not clickable, is it a solution?

### Update 2

I tried to apply the method used on [Method for disabling a button in dat.gui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461964/method-for-disabling-a-button-in-dat-gui)

Following this solution, I have added the extension into `dat.gui`, just after:

```
dat.controllers.FunctionController = (function (Controller, dom, common) {

...

});
```

The following added code snippet is:

```
function blockEvent(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
}

Object.defineProperty(dat.controllers.FunctionController.prototype, "disabled", {
  get: function()
  {
    return this.domElement.hasAttribute("disabled");
  },
  set: function(value)
  {
    if (value)
    {
      this.domElement.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
      this.domElement.addEventListener("click", blockEvent, true);
    }
    else
    {
      this.domElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
      this.domElement.removeEventListener("click", blockEvent, true);
    }
  },
  enumerable: true
});
```

Is extension code well located into `dat.GUI` source?

Then, I set the property "`disabled`" into my code to prevent user from sliding "`controllerRotationx`" with mouse (once start button is pressed):

```
if (animation)
controllerRotationx.__li.disabled = true;
```

Unfortunately, my method doesn't work : when animation is started, I can still move the slider contained into "`controllerRotationx`".

I saw that above link ([Method for disabling a button in dat.gui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461964/method-for-disabling-a-button-in-dat-gui)), this was about a button and not for a slider, does it change anything for my case?

I didn't find an explicit controller for the slider.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do this. The slider is not a form element, there's nothing to disable in the traditional w3c sense. Luckily we can use pointer-events and disable it properly as if it were a form element using just public dat.gui properties.

```
var speeder = menu.add(text, 'speed', -5, 5);
speeder.domElement.style.pointerEvents = "none"
speeder.domElement.style.opacity = .5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @Radio works pretty well. But, with sliders, the slider is a sibling of the text box's DOM element. We need to disable pointer events on the div which contains all the controls (and which is not exposed directly by dat.gui). So,

```
var speeder = menu.add(text, 'speed', -5, 5);
// disables the text box
speeder.domElement.style.pointerEvents = "none"
// disables all controller elements related to "speeder"
speeder.domElement.parentElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for tips 
on my side i hack the Common controller
so able to chainning.

`gui.add(this, '_screenW').disable(true);`

```
  Common.extend(controller,                                   {
    disable: function disable(v) {
      this.domElement.style.pointerEvents = v?"none":"auto";
      this.domElement.style.opacity = v?.5:1;
      return controller;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Start button is pressed, set:

```
controllerRotationx.__li.setAttribute( "style", "display: none" );
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to avoid hidding the __li element (<li> tag ??) of controllerRotationx. Following your idea, I have tried : controllerRotationx.__li.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For the `disabled` part look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461964/method-for-disabling-a-button-in-dat-gui

Comment: @gailat: in your link, this is about a button and not a slider, does it change anything for my case ?

Comment: it should not matter. you just need the controller variable; either a button or a slider should work the same.

Comment: @gailat: ok, I realize that " this.domElement.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");" is not called into code extension, I am still trying to understand why

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem and it works in my case.

```
var params = {
    Rotationx: 0.785,
    get rx() { return this.Rotationx; },
    set rx(val) { /* Do nothing */ }
};

var ctrl = gui.add(params, 'rx', 0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.001).name('Rotation x ');
gui.add({
    clickMeToChangeRotX() {
        params.Rotationx += 0.001;
        ctrl.updateDisplay();
    }
}, 'clickMeToChangeRotX').name('Change rotation x');
```