# Display float value in input field of dat.gui in three js

Tags: dat.gui

[image]

I added inseam inch value 31.8 as default value but it show 32. This is my code.

> var params = {
>                     Inseam: 0,
>                     inseamarea:31.8,
>                 };
>                 var gui = new GUI();
>                 var folder = gui.addFolder( 'Morph Targets' );
>
> ```
>           folder.add( params, 'Inseam', -1, 1 ).step( 0.1 ).onChange( function ( value ) {                    
>               params.inseamarea = 31.8 +(1.4 * value);                    
>           } );
>           folder.add(params, "inseamarea", 31.8).name("Inseam Inch ").listen();
> ```

I want value in float but it show in integer. 
I found a link which i followed. https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/514d4kmy/
and this is my fiddel link where i added my code in same place. https://jsfiddle.net/kwdphca0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use `step()`, e.g. :

```
folder.add(params, "inseamarea", 31.8).step(0.1).name("Inseam Inch ").listen();
```

https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#numbercontroller--datcontrollerscontroller :

> if minimum and maximum specified increment is 1% of the
>   difference otherwise stepValue is 1

EDIT : If you want to disable this controller :

```
let ctrl = folder.add(params, "inseamarea", 31.8).step(0.1).name("Inseam Inch ").listen();
ctrl.domElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Comment: I tried according to you. but issue comes, that i want to display the calculated value here, not the value which is increase according to step

Comment: I don't understand your comment... `inseamarea` will be updated depending on `Inseam` value as intended.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Yes it's working for me. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Is it possible that user can't change value of inseamarea box manually. I means, can we disable this textbox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602189/dat-gui-looking-for-a-way-to-lock-slider-and-prevent-updating-of-values-with-m/38776709